# Working with an Orchard CMS Theme

Tags: orchardcms

I'm working to quickly build a site with Orchard CMS. My site will use a custom theme. I'm editing this theme in Visual Studio. It seems like my changes never take when I update my "Layout-url-homepage.cshtml" file. It seems like there has to be a more elegant way to make updates to a theme and test it more rapidly.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You probably didn't enable the url alternates feature. Or you set-up caching too aggressively. Changes to templates are immediately reflected otherwise.

Comment: As I'm new to Orchard, how do I change my cache settings?

Comment: First things first: do you have caching enabled at all? Did you check that the url alternates feature was enabled?

Comment: Click on Modules in the admin menu on the left, then search for url alternates and click enable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the "Theme Editor" module, by Rickard Magnusson to change the layout of a specific page.
You can see in this article how to do it.
http://support.bind.pt/entries/21855492-Assigning-a-layout-to-a-single-page